# Как НЕ заполнять массив определенными числами?

Tags: c++

Указываю код хотя мне кажется он здесь не пригодится. Можете сразу переходить к "проблемной" строчке внизу.

Как сделать так,чтобы определенные значения(цифры) не могли заполнять массив.То есть:

```
    #include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()
 {
    int rows = 4;
    int columns = 4;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    //Создаем указатель на указатель,и каждый элемент массива указателей будет хранить еще один массив.
    int **arr = new int* [rows];


    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        //в качестве указателя выступает массив и каждая ячейка будет выделять память под еще один массив.
        arr[i] = new int[columns];
    }
    //////////////////////////////////
    //Заполняем массив случайными значениями
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 20+1;

            if (  arr[i][j] == 5||6||7||8||9||10)
            {
                
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Выводим массив в консоль.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    /////////////////////////////////
    //Очищаем память.
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        delete[] arr[i];
    }
    delete[] arr;
    return 0;
}
```

И "проблемная" строчка:

```
if (  arr[i][j] == 5||6||7||8||9||10)
{
    //Нужно чтобы вышеуказанные значения не были в массиве.         
}
```

Comment: И что именно тут мешает проверять, что значение не является одним из запрещенных?

Comment: Я же написал:Нужно чтобы определенные значения не могли заполнять массив.Как это сделать???С помощью if/else,внутри цикла нужен код который предотвратит заполнение вышеприведенными цифрами.

Comment: `if (  arr[i][j] == 5||6||7||8||9||10)` надо писать как `if (arr[i][j] == 5 || arr[i][j] == 5 || ....)` т.е. через `||` пишутся отдельные условия. Но этот if уже поздновато делать, значение же уже попало. Лучше делать `while(1) { X = rand(...); if(X < 5 || X > 10) break; } arr[i][j]=X;`

Comment: @Mike Я знаю что так надо писать,просто у меня возникла ошибка при правильном написании.

Comment: @Mike Кажется я понял,массив же уже заполнился.А вы сделали через while и break.В принципе так тоже можно,спасибо!

Comment: Идея должна быть такой `for (int i = ...) for (int j = ...; j++) { int r = = rand() % 20+1;
 if (is_good_number(r)) arr[i][j] = r; else j--;}`

Comment: @avp, Я уже сам сделал с подсказкой @Mike, но даже не подумал, что можно так сделать `j--` .Спасибо всем за ответы!!!И Вам особенно.С каждым днем узнаю все больше и больше!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ну если чисел не так много и они не большие, то можно примерно таким образом:

```
srand(time(0));
//Всего в черном списке может быть 128 чисел, от 0 до 127
bool black_list[128] = { 0 };
//Заносим 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 в черный список
for (int i = 5; i <= 10; i++)
    black_list[i] = true;

int cols = 4, rows = 4;
int** arr = new int* [rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new int[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        do {
            //Генерируем числа от 0 до 15
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 16;
        //Пропуская от [5, 10]
        } while (black_list[arr[i][j]]);
    }
}

... Далее вывод и удаление матрицы
```

Если же вы перед запуском программы сами устанавливаете числа, которые не хотите видеть в матрице, то вам может подойти вот такой способ:

```
srand(time(0));
int black_list[] = { 5,6,7,8,9,10 };
int cols = 4, rows = 4;
int** arr = new int* [rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    arr[i] = new int[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
        do {
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
        } while (isFind(black_list, 6, arr[i][j]));
    }
}
... Далее вывод и удаление матрицы
```

Функция `ifFind` максимально проста, просто как пример:

```
bool isFind(int* black_list, int size, int value) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        if (black_list[i] == value)
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

Конечно я думаю лучше использовать библиотечную функцию, например `find`.

Тогда условие цикла `do...while` изменится:

```
do {
    arr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
} while (find(black_list, black_list + 6, arr[i][j]) != black_list + 6);
```

Функция `find` возвращает указатель на первый найденый элемент в промежутке `[black_list, black_list + 6)` то есть от начала и до концы массива `black_list`, но без учета `blac_list + 6`. Если элемент не был найден, то функция возвращает второй её параметр, в нашем случае `black_list + 6`.

Если же вы хотите динамически добавлять числа в черный список, то тут лучше использовать динамическую структуру например `vector` или же сами пишите `vector` (или другие структуры) :)

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый,большой ответ,в нем много разных вариантов решения.Задумка с отдельным массивом `bool-ов` тоже крутая.Хотел бы я так быстро находить возможные варианты решений как Вы,как @AlexGlebe ну и другие спецы на форуме.Может с опытом придет.Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: Минусующие вы бы хотя бы говорили, за что минусуете :)

Answer (score 1):

Сначала генерируете правильно, чтобы не было проблем так:

```
arr[i][j] = rand() % (20 - 6) + 1;
if (arr[i][j] >= 5 && arr[i][j] <= 10)
  arr[i][j] += 6 ;
```

или делаете массив нужных чисел :

```
int mass [ 20 - 6 ] = { 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 11 , .... , 20 } ;
..
arr[i][j] = mass [ rand() % (20 - 6) ] ;
```

Comment: ,Знаете  я тоже думал о том чтобы увеличивать значение в случае если число совпадет,**А можно вообще исключить каким нибудь способом определенные числа??? ** Так чтобы они не были в массиве,не могли заполняться???

Comment: попробуйте через маску

Comment: забыл как из индексов получить значения. кажется индексный массив.

Comment: Извините,думал вы пошутили.Я посмотрю как с помощью индексного массива это сделать,спасибо за потраченное время!

Comment: Умно сделать массив нужных чисел,спасибо,даже не подумал что так можно сделать.

Comment: Может тогда уж использовать массив из `bool`, где `true` - число в черном списке, `false` - нет?

Comment: Всё от ситуации зависит. Если числа меньше нуля или с плавающей точкой или с очень большими значениями, то никак. @Павел Ериков

Comment: Я от цикла с проверкой сразу отказался. Недетерминизм это зло. @Павел Ериков

Answer (score -1):

> Как сделать так,чтобы определенные значения(цифры) не могли заполнять
> массив.

так чисел или цифр?

если чисел, то сделать следующее:

**способ 1:**

сформировать массив разрешенных чисел, например через

```
std::vector<int> nums;
```

и выбирать числа для матрицы оттуда, случайным образом определяя индекс в массиве из которого надо взять число

**способ 2:**

сформировать множество запрещённых числе, например через

```
std::set<int> nums = {1, 7, 15};
```

и если случайное число входит в это множество

```
if (nums.find(value) != nums.end())
```

то генерировать случайное число заново (тут вопрос по сравнению со способом 1 в равномерности распределения случайных чисел возникнет, ну да ладно)

если же нужны именно цифры числа, то, что мешает использовать способы 1 и 2 для совокупности цифр, которые можно определить разными способами - или через перевод числа в строку или через выделение цифр при делении по модулю 10

Comment: Для меня это слишком сложные методы,+я использовал динамический массив,так что вы не совсем ответили на мой вопрос...